# Refreshing a form when submit is clicked

Tags: sharepoint-online

Got a calculated field that will concatenate two values but this only seems to work once the form is closed, I want it to refresh once the submit button is clicked so the calculated value update automatically.

Anyone got a simple way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the form in dialog? And is there any code attached to this submit button or just normal OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do that would be (considering you are just concatenating the two values ) is to use Javascript events to concatenate the two values on the client side itself(instead of doing a postback to just get the concatenated value) and let the field show its calculated value on its own after the form is submitted.

Saves bandwidth and time.

E.g.(assumes jQuery)

```
$('#field1').keyup(function () {
    concatUs();
});

$('#field2').keyup(function () {
    concatUs();
});

function concatUs() {
    $('#calcVal').val($('#field1').val() + ' ' + $('#field2').val());
}
```

Use this snippet on your Add/Edit Forms.

Sample here in JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/twwv869o/